# How can I make a method from a different class start when I press a button?

Tags: java, android, class, methods

I have created a method that is supposed to "Deal double damage" to those that are fire and use this method when I press the button.

This is for my high school project that is a simple pokémon-like game which I have a few problems with.

I am using Android Studio.

Constructor for attacks

```
public Attacks(int damage , int accuracy , int critChance , boolean water , boolean fire) {
        this.accuracy = accuracy;
        this.critChance = critChance;
        this.damage = damage;
        this.fire = fire;
        this.water = water;
    }
    public boolean isFire(){
        return fire;
    }
    public int getDamage(){
        return damage;

    }
```

Constructor for characters

```
public Characters(int health, boolean fire) {
        this.health = health;
        this.fire = fire;
        }

    public boolean characterIsFire()
    {
        return fire;
    }

    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }
```

What's gonna happen when I press the button:

This is in a different class. This is in the "Fight View" class, this is where the layout match the code.

```
attackOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override

 public void onClick(View v)
 {
if(fredrikVald)
{

spelare.setText("Fredrik Used Fireball");
 }

 if(jonteVald)
{

spelare.setText("Jonte Used Waterball");
                }
            }
        });
```

The Attack Method.

This is in the Attack Class.

```
 public void attack(Attacks a)
    {
        Characters attacked = characters.get((player_in_turn + 1) % NR_OF_CHARACTERS);
        if(attacked.characterIsFire()&& !a.isFire())
        {
            attacked.health = attacked.getHealth() - (a.getDamage() * 2);
        }
        else
        {
            attacked.health = attacked.health - a.getDamage();
        }
    }
```

I want the attack method to start when I press the button. So that the health of any character, will get lowered by any attack, even if it's fire or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of your Attack class, assume we call this "att". Then you can just add

```
Attacks fireball = new Attacks(/*whatever values you want*/);
att.attack(fireball);
```

to

```
if(fredrikVald)
{
//add code here
spelare.setText("Fredrik Used Fireball");
}
```

and similar code to the waterball portion